# How do I create a second mouse cursor on Surface 3 (not pro)

Tags: mouse, user-interface, microsoft-surface, cursor

I would like one cursor for my touch pad / external mouse, and a second one for the touch screen, both operating independently of one another.

I use both simultaneously quite often and am irritated by the fact that my cursor changes position with every touch tap of the screen.

Comment: Windows does not support doing this by itself, it would require third-party software, but the additional mouse cursor would only exist while the application was running.  Best to get used to this behavior because what you want will not be easy, and it wouldn't solve your problem, because your touch screen and mouse would still only move the primary cursor anyways.

Comment: Thats not an answer to the question. And why do you suggest third party software if the end result wont be any different?

Comment: I mention third-party support because, it's possible to get a second mouse pointer, but mention that having that second mouse pointer can't assigned to the touchscreen.  If I had a more complete answer to submit, I would have submitted it, I was only attempting to help you.  I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: I just dont understand why I would want two cursors if they are going to track with one another per touch screen and touch pad. From your explanation it seems they would overlap each other and behave identically at all times. There is no point to that. Or did I misunderstand?  I may not be able to assign the second cursor to the screen but what about the first cursor? Will one of these behave independently of the other or not? I dont care which one is first or second, I havent put an order to them.